# Proof a series is coverges to a specific sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that the sum of the following series is convergent to :   $1 \ge Sum$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ \left[\left(\frac{2n+1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2n+2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{2n+n}{n}\right)\right]^{-1}$$

Well I succeed to compare it to another series but could only prove its   $2 \ge Sum$.

I would like to get a hint and explanation about the rationale of the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Each of the terms $\frac{2n+k}{n}$ is $>2$, so we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ where $a_n<\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I think there is a tiny $]^{-1}$ at the end!

Comment: @almages That's true .. watch out from the $]^{-1}$

Comment: And you should know that $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots=1$

Comment: The dummy variable is $i$ or $n$?

Comment: Ok i got it , Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oops! I completely missed that. You are right that it diverges as written! But the $i$ must be an error, so I have edited it.

Comment: In fact I did not see that we have a product with $n$ factors, I only saw three factors:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(2n+1)\ldots (2n+n)\geq (2n)^n=2^n n^n$,

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n}{2n+1}\ldots\frac{n}{2n+n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1} {2^n}=1$